# How to update dev plugin in Nativescript?

Tags: nativescript

This may be a noob question but I can't figure out how to update a plugin under devDependencies. I want to update "@nativescript/webpack" which is currently at ~5.0.0-beta.0. There is 5.1 available but I can't update it.

I've tried

```
ns plugin update @nativescript/webpack
npm i -g @nativescript/webpack
npm i @nativescript/webpack --save-dev
```

none of these work.

Answer (score 0):

```
npm i --save-dev @nativescript/webpack
```

is how you do it as per [this comment](https://github.com/NativeScript/NativeScript/issues/9730#issuecomment-1057847393)